# How can I share infinispan cache b/w multiple application deployed to a single wildfly instance

Tags: spring, wildfly, infinispan

I have deployed multiple application to a single wildfly instance, I am starting my wildfly using standalone.xml.

I observe that infinispan cache is not shared b/w these application.
What could be the possible mistake I have been doing.

It will be great if someone can share code for the same...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without showing how you get the Infinispan cache it's hard to help...

Comment: Thanks for replying Radim, below is the repo link:
https://github.com/niteesh2910/testInfinispan

Comment: I'm afraid this is a vague question. Often these problems happen because cluster does not form, e.g. due to network misconfiguration...etc. You should start there...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share the cache you can use the new additional (ISPN 9.3 IIRC) subsystem which can be added to WildFly. The infinispan subsystem is for internal WildFly use-cases only as it is restricted in functionality.

So if you add the ISPN modules for WildFly you can add the additional subsystem.
In this case the WildFly server will take care of the cache lifecycle and you can inject the cache to any of your application(s).

This will give more information:
http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#infinispan_modules_for_wildfly_eap